# Isometry of the adjoint operator

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Suppose that $T$ acts between Banach spaces $T: X \to Y$ and $T$ is surjective. One can define the adjoint operator $T^*:Y^* \to X^*$ by the formula $T^*(\varphi):=\varphi \circ T$. Is it true that if $T^*$ is an isometry then $T$ is also? If so, why is it true?

Comment: no take T to be a non zero functional on X (as you can see Y must be $\mathbb{C}$)

Answer (score 2):

It is true, at least, that (given that $T$ is surjective) if $T$ is an isometry, then $T^*$ is as well. Surjectivity here is particularly important.  Note that
$$
\|T^*\phi\| = 
\sup_{x \in X \setminus \{0\}} \frac{|\phi(T(x))|}{|x|} = 
\sup_{x \in X \setminus \{0\}} \frac{|\phi(T(x))|}{|T(x)|} = 
\sup_{y \in Y \setminus \{0\}} \frac{|\phi(y)|}{|y|} = \|\phi\|
$$
For the non-surjective case, take the right-shift operator as a counterexample.

Comment: This calculation yields that if $T$ is isometric then $T^*$-also. Why the converse is also true?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misread the question.  I'll see if I can find a good answer.

Comment: @QuantumSpace I've fixed my answer; see my edit

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thank you. Changed the vote accordingly :)